# Uniqueness of the algebraic closure of a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm studying abstract algebra and read a theorem on the uniqueness of the algebraic closure of a field. Namely, for any field $F$, the algebraic closure exists and is unique up to isomorphism.

But I have a question: for the reals $\mathbb{R}$ and the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$, we may consider the field of rational functions $\mathbb{C}(x)$ on $x$. *Then*, we can extend $\mathbb{C}(x)$ to get the algebraic closure $\mathbb{D}$ of $\mathbb{C}(x)$, which obviously contains $\mathbb{C}$ itself. Then, $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{D}$ are isomorphic? It seems weird.. is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Your $\mathbb{D}$ is *not* an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{R}$, though.  It contains plenty of elements which are not the solutions to polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: To recap the definition: An algebraic closure of a given field is an algebraically closed field, which is algebraic over the given field. Maybe you want to relook at the proof of the uniqueness (up to isomorphism) of the algebraic closure and check where the fact, that the closure is algebraic over the given field, is needed.

Comment: Oh, thanks Hayden and MooS. I am an idiot.. hahaha..

Comment: Nevertheless the fields $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{D}$ are isomorphic.